# Calling a method from template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I seem to have a problem with calling a method from a `django` template. Given the model:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Galerie"

    def photo_count(self):
        return self.photo_set.count()

    def random_image(self):
        return self.photo_set.get(id=random.randint(1,self.photo_count()))

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imgur_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Data utworzenia', auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

where Gallery is foreignKey for Photo
views.py:

```
def index(request):
    galleries = Gallery.objects.get(is_active=True)
    if galleries.count() is 0:
        messages.warning(request, "Niestety, żadna galeria nie jest aktywna, zaglądnij niebawem!")
        return redirect(reverse(home))
    elif galleries.count() is 1:
        return render(request, 'gallery/home.html', {'gallery': galleries})
    else:
         return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', {'galleries': galleries})
```

I want to do this in template:

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
         {{ gallery.random_image }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

The result I get is:

```
[ Photo object ]
[]
[]
[]
```

But when i call

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
    {{ gallery.photo_count }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

The result is correct.

Why does this not work?

Comment: Can you include your `views.py` as well?

Comment: Also , if you don't mind - could you fix your indents on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are complicated a little bit.

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Galerie"

    def random_image(self):
        return self.photo_set.order_by('?')[0] if self.photo_set.count() else None

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imgur_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Data utworzenia', auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and in the template,

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
    {% if gallery.random_image %}
        {{ gallery.random_image }} <br />
    {% else %}
        No images found.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more on [`order_by` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Note that `?` could prove slightly heavy. If so, get thelist of ids of the `photo_set` associated with this gallery object, and get a random id from this list, rather than doing a 
`random.randint(1,self.photo_count())`

Comment: Works, simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add @property to your fonction.

```
@property
def photo_count(self):
    return self.photo_set.count()
```

Comment: i tried adding @property to both methods, all combinations produce same results